# Generic pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I understand that according to standard `void *` is generic pointer, and `void **` is not. So, in my program, I am trying to cast `void *` and not directly type cast `void **` but I am not getting expected results. I think I am missing something very basic in here.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

void check(void **p) 
{
    printf("value:  %d\n", *(int *)*p);
}

int main()
{

    int a[] = {6,2,5,1,8};

    int *p;
    p = a;

    void **val;
    val = (void *)p;

    check(val);


    return 0;
}
```

I have a `void **` pointer `val`, which is pointing to `int *` but casted to `void *`. I pass this to function `check`, which is expecting `void **`. In my `printf`, I first cast `*p` (which is `void *`) to `int *` and then derefernce it. I get some random value. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `val = &p;` should be `val = p;`

Comment: EDIT: I pasted the wrong example before. I was working on two different cases. Sorry about that.

Comment: umm you just `void check(void *p) 
{
    printf("value:  %d\n", *(int *)p);
}` There is no need to use the `void**`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY since the author wanted a "`void **` pointer `val`, which is pointing to `int *`", `val = &p` is correct for his purpose, although the code is still wrong because `void**` is not guaranteed to be convertible with `int**`. Why did you propose to replace it with `val = p`? With your amendment, `val` is no longer a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the call to `printf`:

```
printf("value:  %d\n", *(int *)*p);
```

In `main`, `val` (which is a `void **`) contains the contents of a `int *`.  This is then passed to `check`, where is now called `p`.  This needs to be casted to an `int *` to read correctly:

```
printf("value:  %d\n", *(int *)p);
```

Of course, since a `void **` is not a generic pointer, it doesn't make much sense to do this.  Best to get rid of the extra level of indirection which isn't being used anyway:

```
void check(void *p) 
{
    printf("value:  %d\n", *(int *)p);
}

int main()
{

    int a[] = {6,2,5,1,8};

    int *p;
    p = a;

    void *val;
    val = p;

    check(val);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i was close, but I dereferenced it at the place where I shouldnt have. THanks dbush

Comment: Casting an `int**` to a `void**` does not make any sense.

Comment: @Quentin It made more sense in the context of the original question before it was edited.  I've updated the answer to remove reference to it to avoid confusion, and offered an alternative that makes more sense.

Comment: @dbush thanks for that correction -- downvote reversed :)

Answer (score 0):

Change  `val = &p;` to `val = p;`

Probably it was a kind of "typo" since you had already passed the value once correctly and later also dereferenced it.

EDIT:
You can change: `val = (void *)p;` to `val = (void *)&p;`

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, `void**` is *not* a generic pointer. It is a pointer that point to an object of type `void*`, and nothing else. Using a cast to point it at an object of type `int*` is type punning.

In your case, you should simply cast your `int*` to `void*`, and back to `int*` again. No `void**` involved.

Comment: But the topic starter wanted to pass a pointer-to-pointer! He can do by converting `int**` to `void*`. Then, in the `check` function, he should extract the value by `**(int**)p`. It works because any pointer is guaranteed to survive the round trip to `void*` and back to the original pointer type.

Comment: @Ant_222 but there's no `int**` in there. The only pointer-to-pointer is the one artificially created for `check`'s parameter.

Comment: when you pass `&p` into `check()`, it is exactly `int**`.

Comment: @Ant_222 did you mix up the question with user8's answer? The call is `check(val)`, where `val` is (converted) `p`.

Comment: I mean the current edition of the question. The `check()` function takes a `void**`, which is a pointer to a pointer, whereas the programmer invokes it with an `int*`, which it *not* a pointer to a pointer. The code can be made to work on certain platforms and compilers if `val = (void *)p;` is replaced with `val = &p`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/sSUMdZ1Q) is the working version.

Comment: @Ant_222 hence my advice to *not* rely on undefined behaviour and not use `void**`.

Comment: And a good one, too. I just proposed a correction that made the code work as the original posted inteded it to work: by passing a pointer to pointer.